# Particular image won't show in UIButton

Tags: xcode, image, button

I am trying to show the following image in a UIButton.

[image]

For some reason, the delete icon won't work here but any other image does. Is there something wrong with the image?

[image]

Comment: Try "WhiteDeleteButton" only...

Answer (score 0):

The button wasn't added to the target membership